# Unable to access file adapter using JMS

Tags: tibco

I am not able to retrieve records from flat file using fileadapter ver 5.6 with JMS. It always show this error at console,

Startup error. SDK Error: Could not open JMS shared library  jms, DllError.
The error occurred on starting the adapter after initialization. The Repository URL is D:\bala\input\Work\AT_adfiles_53689.dat and the Configuration URL is Fileadapter/FileAdapterConfiguration..

Its working fine with RV but not with JMS. Kindly help me out..

Comment: Can you please post your EMS installation path and your File Adapter tra settings. The file should be somewhere like `C:\tibco\adapter\adfiles\<version>\bin\adfiles.tra`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to the problem above. First look into the AT_adfiles_xxxxx.tra under your working adapter directory. Look for the line where it said "tibco.env.PATH=xxxxx"

First of all, look into all those bins directory, you will find some of the bin folder actually contain libeay32.dll" and "ssleay32.dll". The problem is where the sdk\5.5\bin contain different version of libeay32.dll" and "ssleay32.dll" to other folder. In order for you to run this correctly, all of libeay32.dll" and "ssleay32.dll" should be in the same version.

So which ever version you decided to use, make a copy of that to other folders that contain the same file. What i did to preserve the original version of those is by renaming the original with .bak at the end.

This should allow you to test the file adapter!